# Using docx4j to bold specify word in a paragrah

Tags: java, docx4j

I try to generate a simple text like this by Java into docx document

`This is **bold** test`

I search the online this part of the code will be the close one, however it bolds the whole line, not a specific word

```
ObjectFactory factory = Context.getWmlObjectFactory();
P p = factory.createP();
R r = factory.createR();
Text text = factory.createText();
RPr rpr = factory.createRPr();
text.setValue("This is bold test");
BooleanDefaultTrue boldTrue = new BooleanDefaultTrue();
boldTrue.setVal(Boolean.TRUE);
rpr.setB(boldTrue);
r.getContent().add(text);
p.getContent().add(r);
r.setRPr(this.rpr);
mainDocumentPart.getContent().add(p);
```

This will bold all the paragraph, however I just want that word "bold" into bold, and keep remain unbold.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [docx4j webapp](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/PartsList.html) or [Word Helper AddIn](https://www.docx4java.org/forums/announces/docx4j-helper-addin-v3-3-available-t2393.html) to generate the code you need from a suitable sample Word docx.

In this case:

```
    // Create object for p
    P p = wmlObjectFactory.createP(); 
        // Create object for r
        R r = wmlObjectFactory.createR(); 
        p.getContent().add( r); 
            // Create object for t (wrapped in JAXBElement) 
            Text text = wmlObjectFactory.createText(); 
            JAXBElement<org.docx4j.wml.Text> textWrapped = wmlObjectFactory.createRT(text); 
            r.getContent().add( textWrapped); 
                text.setValue( "This is "); 
                text.setSpace( "preserve"); 
        // Create object for r
        R r2 = wmlObjectFactory.createR(); 
        p.getContent().add( r2); 
            // Create object for rPr
            RPr rpr = wmlObjectFactory.createRPr(); 
            r2.setRPr(rpr); 
                // Create object for b
                BooleanDefaultTrue booleandefaulttrue = wmlObjectFactory.createBooleanDefaultTrue(); 
                rpr.setB(booleandefaulttrue); 
                // Create object for bCs
                BooleanDefaultTrue booleandefaulttrue2 = wmlObjectFactory.createBooleanDefaultTrue(); 
                rpr.setBCs(booleandefaulttrue2); 
            // Create object for t (wrapped in JAXBElement) 
            Text text2 = wmlObjectFactory.createText(); 
            JAXBElement<org.docx4j.wml.Text> textWrapped2 = wmlObjectFactory.createRT(text2); 
            r2.getContent().add( textWrapped2); 
                text2.setValue( "bold"); 
        // Create object for r
        R r3 = wmlObjectFactory.createR(); 
        p.getContent().add( r3); 
            // Create object for t (wrapped in JAXBElement) 
            Text text3 = wmlObjectFactory.createText(); 
            JAXBElement<org.docx4j.wml.Text> textWrapped3 = wmlObjectFactory.createRT(text3); 
            r3.getContent().add( textWrapped3); 
                text3.setValue( " test"); 
                text3.setSpace( "preserve");
```

Then your mainDocumentPart.getContent().add(p);